# How to browse an image and display it in Python?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have this code here:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog



class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        self.title("Python Tkinter Dialog Widget")
        self.minsize(640, 400)

        self.labelFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text = "Open File")
        self.labelFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 20, pady = 20)

        self.button()



    def button(self):
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.labelFrame, text = "Browse A File",command = self.fileDialog)
        self.button.grid(column = 1, row = 1)


    def fileDialog(self):

        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir =  "/", title = "Select A File", filetype =
        (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")) )
        self.label = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text = "")
        self.label.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        self.label.configure(text = self.filename)






root = Root()
root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to display the image I have chosen in browsing menu.

Currently I have `self.label.configure(text = self.filename)` to give me return filename, but how can I display the image itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        self.title("Python Tkinter Dialog Widget")
        self.minsize(640, 400)

        self.labelFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text = "Open File")
        self.labelFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 20, pady = 20)

        self.button()


    def button(self):
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.labelFrame, text = "Browse A File",command = self.fileDialog)
        self.button.grid(column = 1, row = 1)


    def fileDialog(self):

        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir =  "/", title = "Select A File", filetype =
        (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")) )
        self.label = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text = "")
        self.label.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        self.label.configure(text = self.filename)

        img = Image.open(self.filename)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

        self.label2 = Label(image=photo)
        self.label2.image = photo 
        self.label2.grid(column=3, row=4)

root = Root()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfect! how can I resize it?

Comment: You can resize it using img = img.resize((250, 250)) just after the Image.open statement.